# SQL - select max over two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table from which I need to select `max(bar)` for every `foo`
**and** exclude any record if **both** `foo` and `bar` are lower than `foo` and `bar` of another record.

Data:

```
+------+------+
| foo  | bar  |
+------+------+
|    5 |   30 |
|    5 |   40 |
|    6 |   60 |
|    6 |   65 |
|    6 |   95 |
|    7 |   10 |
|    7 |   30 |
+------+------+
```

Expected result:

```
+------+----------+
| foo  | max(bar) |
+------+----------+
|    6 |       95 |
|    7 |       30 |
+------+----------+
```

I'm stuck with

```
+------+----------+
| foo  | max(bar) |
+------+----------+
|    5 |       40 |
|    6 |       95 |
|    7 |       30 |
+------+----------+
```

I've tried different variations of the following query joined to itself with no luck.

```
select foo, max(bar) from mytable
group by foo
order by foo, bar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is almost there.  You just need an appropriate filtering condition.  Here is one way to do the filtering using `not exists`:

```
select foo, max(bar)
from mytable t
where not exists (select 1
                  from mytable t2
                  where t.foo < t2.foo and t.bar < t2.bar
                 )
group by foo
order by foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Version with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT MAX(mt1.bar), mt1.foo 
FROM myTable mt1 
LEFT JOIN myTable mt2 ON (mt1.foo < mt2.foo AND mt1.bar < mt2.bar)
WHERE mt2.foo IS NULL
GROUP BY mt1.foo
;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f65a60/7)

Answer (score -2):

Try getting the max of each column in a subquery and and then trying your group by

```
select t1.foo, max(t1.bar) 
from mytable t1, (select max(foo) foo, max(bar) bar from mytable) t2 
where t1.foo = t2.foo 
or t1.bar = t2.bar 
group by foo;
```

Comment: @PM77-1 Yep, I've tried and yes it worked. Your left join solution is better and cleaner though.